# Probability that any given point on a line will fall within a given distance of another

Tags: probability

I have a line (1D vector with finite, known length) along which I choose a given number of points (`n`) at random without replacement:

[image]

Each point has a width = 1pt and any point along the line has an equal chance of being chosen.

Is there a method by which I can approximate the probability that any given point will fall within a certain distance (e.g. 150pt) of another at any given value of `n`? e.g. to answer a question such as "If I choose 150 points at random on a vector of 2000pt length, X% of the points on average will fall within 50pt of one another".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will start with giving you the 'smartass' answer. Yes, there is a method that can give you an approximation; monte carlo simulation. You could write a script, using for example R, that generates your random points, and then evaluates the distance between those points (a distance of <1 would indicate overlapping points).

If such an approach is unacceptable, unfortunately, I doubt I will be able to give you an answer to your exact question. I have seen a simplified problem related to yours however, which I will share with you. Who knows, it might push you in the right direction. More specifically, I can give you a formula that gives the probability that none of the points on the line overlap.

Similarly to your problem, I have a line with a known length, for simplicity lets say 1. This line will be randomly cut in N places (with the probability being uniformly distributed along the line). This results in N+1 line segments, with each a certain length. I am interested in the length L of the shortest line segment.
For N=1 it can be easily proven (using an integral) that the probability equals 1-2L. 
For N=2, it can be proven (using a double integral) that the probability becomes (1-3L)^2
This made me suspect that the formula for any N would be (1-(N+1)L)^N.
This can indeed be proven using full induction.

Thus for your problem, you could calculate the probabilty that NONE of your points fall within a distance of L of eachother using (1-(N+1)L)^N. (actually this would be a lower bound for that probability, since your problem does not restrict the length of the first and last segment.

Good luck with your problem.